# Pandas groupby and transform working inconsistently(with NaN values)?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to broadcast some group-level variables to each row. The grouping variable has several entries that are NaN.

I used this code before:

```
df.groupby(by="location")["id"].transform(lambda x: len(x))
```

Normally it works fine even if the grouping variables had NaN values. So I used this and everything was fine, there was just no index for the rows where the grouping variable had NaN. To clarify, I use "id" as the selected variable purely to not run the operation on all columns.

I now have a dataset where this type of operation returns an error when the grouping variable has NaN values:

```
  f"Length mismatch: Expected axis has {old_len} elements, new "
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 316 elements, new values have 473 elements
```

I struggle to find what is different here. The whole dataset I am talking about is available [here](https://github.com/BorutFlis/Scripts/blob/b126dacc7499b22e8e960485342242dcc7a1da4f/separate%23woke.csv).

I hypothesized it could be something to do with the grouping variable having a lot groups with only one row, but I experimented and added a column with bigger groups and the same mistake happens when some values are NaN.

Basically all potential grouping variables in this df return an error if there are NaN values and work fine if they are NaNs, so there could be something about the data-frame as a whole.

**EDIT**

There seems to be a problem in the 1.2.5 version, updating it to the new 1.3.3 version of pandas solved the problem.

Comment: this dataset doesnt seem legit

Comment: There is a link to the dataset. I don't know how to sample it to improve understanding.

Comment: @adirabargil what about it?

Comment: it doesnt look like a legit csv file or whatever type it is, can you show some code samples?

Comment: Your error is not reproducible with the dataset you provided. I get no error when I run `df.groupby(by="location")["id"].transform(lambda x: len(x))`  on pandas 1.3.2

Comment: Also works fine for me, which pandas version do you have?

Comment: I have 1.2.5, will update and see.

Comment: @BorutFlis on a side note - you can avoid the `lambda` and use `df.groupby(by="location")["id"].transform('size')` or instead of 'size' use 'count' if you only want to consider non-NaNs...

Comment: @JonClements thanks. When you say non-NaNs you mean for the values of "id"?

Comment: Yeah... so if location A had IDs of `[1, NaN, 2]` then `size` will return 3 and `count` will return 2 for Location `A`, and if it was `[NaN, NaN, NaN]` then `size` will still return 3 but `count` will return 0

Comment: Thank you everybody! Yes, it was a version problem.